# Adapting php code to use mysqli instead of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have code that works with php 5.6 but not with php 7.0. It's very short, so I thought I'd be able to modify it without a problem, but I was wrong. The original script is below, followed by my attempt to use mysqli. Could some kind person please show me what I need to do to get it right?

OLD CODE

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "database_name";
$db_user = "user_name";
$db_pass = "pass";

$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die("Could not  connect to database as ".$db_user."@".$db_host."!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Could not select database ".$db_name);
?>
```

NEW CODE

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "database_name";
$db_user = "user_name";
$db_pass = "pass";

$link = new mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');
mysqli_select_db($db_name) or die("Could not select database ".$db_name);
?>
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stackoverflow. I don't think this is a question for stackoverflow, since you can answer it for yourself by the following steps: 1. open http://google.com - 2: Seach for "php mysqli connect" - 3: Enjoy the 234589734 examples and simply do it like they did :)

Comment: It's question for stackoverflow :) Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

Add `$link` in `mysqli_select_db`, refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) for more information

```
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name)
```

Comment: Hi Swellar, thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion but got a blank screen, which is what's happened with each code modification I've tried, which is quite frustrating. Best Wishes. :)